# Coldfusion JSoup replace elements in head tag

Tags: coldfusion, jsoup, element, cfml

I cannot figure out how to combine multiple script tags into 1 using jsoup and coldfusion, here's my code placed in the application.cfc page.

```
        <cfsavecontent variable="htmlContents">
            <cfoutput>
                <cfinclude template="#arguments.TargetPage#">
            </cfoutput>
        </cfsavecontent>
        <cfscript>
        jsoup = createObject("java", "org.jsoup.Jsoup");
        html = jsoup.parse(htmlContents);
        head = html.head();
        children = head.children();
        cssdata = "";
        scriptdata = "";

        if(ArrayLen(children)) {
            for (i=1; i<ArrayLen(children); i++) {
                if (children[i].tagName() EQ "style") {
                    returnHTML = children[i].html();
                    if (returnHTML NEQ "") {
                        cssdata = cssdata & returnHTML;
                        children[i].remove();
                    }
                } else if (children[i].tagName() EQ "script") {
                    returnHTML = children[i].html();
                    if (returnHTML NEQ "") {
                        scriptdata = scriptdata & returnHTML;
                        children[i].remove();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        WriteOutput(html);
        </cfscript>
```

The result should be taking this:

```
<script>
//script
</script>
<script>
//script
</script>
<script>
//script
</script>
<script>
//script
</script>
```

and turning it into this

```
<script>
//script//script//script//script
</script>
```

Any step in the right direction with java objects and coldfusion would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use jsoup, but I wouldn't recommend using it this way.  There may be other JS params that you need and adding all scripts into a single block may cause problems (ie, defer).

As a practice, we add all CSS & JSS script to an array object and then output them to the HTML head section using CFHTMLHEAD.

```
<cfset AddToHeader = arraynew(1)>
<cfsavecontent variable="tempJS">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    console.log('hello world');
});
</script>
</cfsavecontent>
<cfset arrayappend(AddtoHeader, tempJS)>
...
<cfhtmlhead text="#arraytolist(AddtoHeader, chr(10))#">
```

Which web server are you using? If IIS, check out http://www.iispeed.com/  This Google PageSpeed plugin will automatically move scripts (& CSS) to the header intelligently, concat scripts based on the best file size for each device, minify, control caching and embed inline when needed.  (I've used IISpeed with ColdFusion 9 & 10 with absolutely no issues.)

You can experiment with PageSpeed and your website by using the demo at

http://www.iispeed.com/pagespeed-demo

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @James, this would be exactly what I need except the scripts I am trying to combine are auto-generated by coldfusion's ajax functionality, so it would give me roughly 300 script tags that look something like this:`<script type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */
ColdFusion.Ajax.importTag('CFAJAXPROXY');         /* ]]> */</script>`

Comment: I've avoided CF's ajax tags and use jQuery's ajax function instead. I don't feel comfortable about using closed CFFunctions I can't control and that aren't updated when the rest of the JS libraries (like jQuery) are updated.  (Example: CF11 comes with jQuery 1.6.1 from 2011.)

If I remember right, ColdFusion likes to control the output of it's generated widgets and throws some of it in the HEAD section. You may not be able to be capture by CFContent and is also one of the reasons I avoided it.

Comment: According to this recent Adobe BugBase response, the Ajax UI components may be deprecated in CF12.  https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3043516   There are other ways to do ajax requests. CF's ajax components may make Ajax easy, but using them is also the fastest way to accrue technical debt.  Here are some UI alternatives that will be more beneficial to you in the long run. http://static.raymondcamden.com/cfuitherightway/